# Index was out of range exception populating form fields

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am building a html form using a ASP.NET Html helper. In the code example below, I am creating 5 fields which are populated by the TradeRisks list. If the list does not contain 5 items, I will encounter an “Index was out of range” exception. I would like to allow the form user to submit changes to the fields and then view the changes when they are saved. The user may not populate all fields.

I have managed to work around this problem by implementing some conditional logic, however I am unsure if this is the best approach and I think there must be a better way. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    <div class="form-row align-items-center mb-1">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.FormData.TradeRisks[i].Description)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: What is _TradeRisk_ and where is the iterator that gives you that _r_ element used in the loop?. Do you have this code contained in some other loop?

Comment: The page model. Formdata is a viewmodel which contains a List<TradeRisk>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use 5 textbox, the best approach is  implementing some conditional logic.

If there is no need to put the 5 textbox, you could set the `r.FormData.TradeRisks.Count` as the for condition's limitation.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < r.FormData.TradeRisks.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="form-row align-items-center mb-1">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.FormData.TradeRisks[i].Description)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```